# What Android API?

Tags: android

I need to know what api of android to use so that my app will be supported by a majority of users. I tried on the web and searching here but cannot find much info that is not dated.

I don't want to worry that if I want to add something that needs a higher api that I can't because I picked a really low api.

So what api is everyone using at the moment and when do people normally move up to newer ones?

I have some experience in javascript games and some java programs so I want to make an app as I have left it long enough. I have downloaded eclipse and the android sdk I just need to decide on the api.

Any tips would be great, thanks!

Comment: Depends on what you wan't to do and your target group...

Comment: possible duplicate of [What android version should I target when developing new apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775566/what-android-version-should-i-target-when-developing-new-apps)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html to make an informed decision that fits your requirements.

Answer (score 2):

you can use any API you want, set your minimum API you want to support and the one you want to build on

example:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18"/>
```

Comment: The question isn't "what API _can_ I use?" it's "what API _should_ I use?" This doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @Michelle which is based on opinion, my answer gives the OP an example of how to use a range and not worry about using one so yes it does question the question, infact it goes beyond the answer since its how to properly support all API's

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, it boils down to the decision between 2.3.3 and 4.x as the 3.x versions tend to be nonexisting in the wild.

Here some data from one of my apps, released in February 2013. I decided to support down to 2.2 at the time, but the data suggests that it wasn't really worth it.

Android 4.3 / 2,40 %
Android 4.2 / 8,34 %
Android 4.1 / 49,35 %
Android 4.0.3 - 4.0.4 / 16,43 %

Android 3.0 / 0,04 %
Android 3.1 / 0,04 %
Android 3.2 / 0,18 %

Android 2.2 / 2,61 %
Android 2.3.3 - 2.3.7 / 20,63 %